# Can't read .scss file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, vaadin7

I'm at my first Jenkins's build and I'm trying with a very basic vaadin application but when I do the build I keep getting these errors:

```
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\xxx_vaadin_jdk7-1.0-Manual_Test_VM\workspace\src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes\.svn\styles.scss could not be read!
[ERROR] Compiling theme "VAADIN\themes\.svn" failed
```

as if it can't process the above file. As far as I know, all the configuration in Jenkins has been done correctly, but I can't figure out why I keep getting this error. Do I need some kind of plugin by any chance?

EDIT:
To add to it, what's I'm trying to do is to build the application in Jenkins. So, I have a basic vaadin application (the most basic you can have that comes out of the box when you create a vaadin application). I was expecting to be able to build the application successfully, but it looks like something has gone wrong.
What I've done was creating the application in vaadin using eclipse, then upload it to a shared SVN repo and from there to Jenkins.
The folder structure in the SVN repo is this in the screenshot

[image]

So in jenkins I've actually checked the .svn folder and it doesn't contain the styles.scss which accounts for the error, but what I don't get is why. Hopefully that gives a bit more context : -)


**EDIT and possible solution:**
Right, some intersting updates on this, which I thought I'd share.
There were effectively two problems with my build in Jenkins:
1)that SASS issue described here;
2) the version of the compiler (1.7 in eclipse but 1.8 in the pom file, so I had to manually change from 1.8 to 1.7 inside the pom file). This problem became evident after resolving the first
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project vaadin.test.jdk7: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]`

Right, so about problem 1: it seems to be due to this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>             
    <configuration>
        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
        <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
        <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
        <compileReport>false</compileReport>
        <style>OBF</style>
        <strict>true</strict>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>update-theme</goal>
                 <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation
                <goal>compile-theme</goal> -->
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>               
</plugin>
```

I went through all the goal statements and comment them out 1 by 1 till I found the source of the problem, which seems to be `<goal>compile-theme</goal>`
Fair enough there is a default comment there saying Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation, although I'm not too sure what that means.
So in essence I sorted that out but I don't know if this is the right way and what and if there are any implications. Any idea?

Comment: A little bit more context (what are you trying to do, and what do you expect) and a bit more code than just a snippet can be helpful. 
Is the file actually there? it seems a bit strange that it is looking for a file in a `.svn` directory (is it an SVN project)?

Comment: I am not familiar with vaadin, but it looks like there is a job that collects all .sccs files and tries to compile them. In that case I think you might want to excluse files in `.svn` because that folder contains svn information that should not be part of the sources you are trying to compile (is themes an svn subproject? if not why is the .svn folder there? Can you remove the directory from your project?)

Comment: Let me try to exclude them and see what happens. I'm playing around with my pom.xml too as I suspect there might be some plugin in there that Jenkins isn't too happy about

Comment: Right, interesting developments, I've updated the main thread as it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

As I also had the same problem while Jenkins building my maven VAADIN project, I simply copied **ALL** .scss files into the .svn folder from themes. In your case: ..\workspace\src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes.svn. Then the build passed.

Comment: To complete my answer: maven cannot find the .scss files in the .svn folder that is the reason why it fails. The error "... could not be read!" is misleading in this case because the files are missing from there. Usually Maven shouldn't look into those folders.